Bug when trying to post a question with code in it
I'm stuck trying to post a question with this ridiculous error which took me forever to resolve to no avail.

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as
code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button
or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?]
toolbar icon.

The error is incorrect as I can prove and post it here: I copy pasted the following from a simple text file and yet it shows me that aforementioned error so it obviously is a bug. It works here in meta, this is the content of my question:

I have finally resolved this thread where I made this QB writer but now I'm trying to apply RLE compression based on the Qubicle documentation but I don't know what I am doing wrong. The following script works for self.compressed=0 perfectly, but although it also runs without errors with self.compressed=1, the resulting .qb file does not open in Qubicle resulting in Abstract error. I can see the .qb file reduces in size. But I'm definitely doing something incorrectly in save_matrix_compressed.
import struct
from typing import List, Tuple

class QbMatrix:
    def __init__(self, name: str, size_x, size_y, size_z, data, pos: Tuple[int, int, int]):
        self.name = name
        self.pos = pos
        self.data = data
        self.size_x = size_x
        self.size_y = size_y
        self.size_z = size_z

class Qb:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.version: int = 0x0101
        self.colorFormat: int = 0
        self.zAxisOrientation: int = 0
        self.compressed: int = 0
        self.visibilityMaskEncoded: int = 0
        self.matrixList: List[QbMatrix] = []

    def add_matrix(self, name: str, data, pos: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> None:
        self.matrixList.append(QbMatrix(name, data, pos))

    def save(self, filename: str) -> None:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f: # type(f) = <class '_io.BufferedWriter'>
            self.compressed = 0  # Set compression to RLE

            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.version))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.colorFormat))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.zAxisOrientation))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.compressed))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", self.visibilityMaskEncoded))
            f.write(struct.pack("I", len(self.matrixList)))

            for matrix in self.matrixList: # QbMatrix
                self.save_matrix(f, matrix)

    def save_matrix(self, file: object, matrix: QbMatrix) -> None:
        file.write(struct.pack("B", len(matrix.name)))
        file.write(struct.pack(str(len(matrix.name.encode('ascii')))+"s", matrix.name.encode('ascii')))
        size_x = matrix.size_x
        size_y = matrix.size_y
        size_z = matrix.size_z
        file.write(struct.pack("III", size_x, size_y, size_z))
        file.write(struct.pack("iii", matrix.pos[0], matrix.pos[1], matrix.pos[2]))

        if self.compressed == 1:
            self.save_matrix_compressed(file, matrix)
        else:
            self.save_matrix_uncompressed(file, matrix)

    def save_matrix_uncompressed(self, file: object, matrix: QbMatrix) -> None:
        for color in matrix.data:
            file.write(bytes([c for c in color]))

    def save_matrix_compressed(self, file: object, matrix: QbMatrix) -> None:
        size_x = matrix.size_x
        size_y = matrix.size_y
        size_z = matrix.size_z
        data = matrix.data

        def convert_color(color_tuple):
            return (color_tuple[0] << 24) | (color_tuple[1] << 16) | (color_tuple[2] << 8) | color_tuple[3]

        index = 0
        while index < size_x * size_y * size_z:
            count = 1
            while (index + count) < (size_x * size_y * size_z) and data[index + count] == data[index]:
                count += 1

            color_data = convert_color(data[index])
            if count > 2:
                file.write(struct.pack("I", 2))  # CODEFLAG
                file.write(struct.pack("I", count))
                file.write(struct.pack("I", color_data))
                index += count
            else:
                for _ in range(count):
                    file.write(struct.pack("I", color_data))
                    index += 1

        file.write(struct.pack("I", 6))  # NEXTSLICEFLAG



def test_write_qb_file():
    size_x=4
    size_y=4
    size_z=4

    colors = {
        (2, 1, 0): (140, 40, 17, 255),
        (2, 0, 3): (114, 32, 186, 255),
        (1, 1, 3): (233, 46, 88, 255),
        (1, 2, 1): (197, 99, 132, 255),
        (1, 0, 3): (228, 9, 122, 255),
        (2, 0, 2): (149, 83, 110, 255),
        (2, 2, 3): (128, 248, 166, 255),
        (2, 2, 1): (236, 131, 28, 255),
        (3, 2, 1): (13, 202, 21, 255),
        (0, 3, 0): (193, 191, 96, 255)
    }

    EMPTY_COLOR = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    data = [colors[x, y, z]
                if colors.get((x,y,z)) else EMPTY_COLOR 
                for z in range(size_z)
                for y in range(size_y)
                for x in range(size_x)]

    file: str = "C:/out.qb"
    layer: QbMatrix = QbMatrix("cube", size_x, size_y, size_z, data, (0, 0, 0))
    qb: Qb = Qb()
    qb.matrixList.append(layer)
    qb.save(file)

test_write_qb_file()


The automatic detection indeed is flaky (e.g. triggering on link markdown) but in your draft there are indeed some unformatted code parts. Both self.compressed=0 and self.compressed = 1 stand out as unformatted.

yes i did format them initially with self.compressed=0 then i removed the formatting on suspicion that it may have caused it

FWIW, aside from formatting please be mindful of the advice on the guidance for a Minimal, Reproducible Example. There is tons of code with lots of redundancy (e.g. it should be sufficient to struct.pack any value instead of all of them) and scaffolding (e.g is add_matrix actually used? are all the layers of test_write, save, save_uncompressed, ... actually needed?). Critically, it is not clear where you set self.compressed to trigger the issue - modifying all obvious occurrences and running the code does not fail for me.

@MisterMiyagi yes sorry I'm aware of it but unfortunately for this example it is not possible to make it more minimal as there is no way to truly test the output in Qubicle if I were to reduce/omit other parts of the code. So it's basically not possible to reproduce the problem with a smaller example. Am I mistaken? Critically, it is not clear where you set self.compressed to trigger the issue > I'm not sure what you mean by this? The code runs well with self.compressed=1 it will never fail. But what I mean is that the resulting .qb file cannot be opened in Qubicle.

"But what I means is that the resulting .qb file cannot be opened in Qubicle." Please be mindful that your question never says that! The question says you get an Abstract Error with no further details on that, and then that "The following script works […] not for self.compressed = 1". This implies the script fails with an Abstract Error if you set self.compressed = 1.

@MisterMiyagi ah sorry for that let me edit it again. My apologies.

Can you try posting this content as a question on main? Also it would make sense to add the (complete) error traceback to the question (The traceback is very useful in figuring out the issue / narrowing it down).

@AbdulAzizBarkat I can't.. it does not work hence i posted this as a bug here. It's currently in draft on main. Or do you mean another site for "main"? It's on stackoverflow.com as draft. Also Qubicle does not provide the traceback. It only says at the bottom of the Qubicle software: Error An uncaught exception occurred during the execution of AcnOpen. Maybe you have moderator privilege to post on my behalf? I had a friend also review the code and he said it looks good. Maybe it's a Qubicle bug?

I am not a moderator (they have a diamond next to their name), not to mention even moderators can't post on behalf of other users. I mentioned trying to post it since you'd edited the content a bit.

I just tried creating the question with a 1-rep account using the content that you provided here and end-up with no errors in the review step, so I assume I could post it. Is there something I'm missing that causes the error for you?

@rene no nothing you are missing. it is just plain a bug. my workaround was to copy the draft content and put it in a text file and then remove everything in the draft content and put some random pure text in it without code or links. let it sit there for a few seconds until it auto saves to overwrite the previous draft content. and then copy the content from the text file back into stackoverflow. This workaround worked but may be a bit tricky/technical. definitely needs to be fixed this bug.

" definitely needs to be fixed this bug" - the reality seems to not agree with you. At this point we can only conclude that the requirement to jump through invisible hoops to post large wads of code is "good enough". Or it'd have gotten attention years ago. And of course you can post this on meta, meta does not have the same restrictions as the main site for the very purpose of being able to post requests for assistance like this.

I discovered a workaround for this issue. My solution involved copying the draft content to a text file, clearing the draft content, and replacing it with arbitrary plain text (without any code or links). After allowing it to remain for a few seconds to trigger an autosave and overwrite the previous draft, I copied the content from the text file back into Stack Overflow. While effective, this workaround may be somewhat intricate and technical. Clearly, this bug requires attention and resolution.
