I do not understand how I can narrow down a question which has been closed for not being detailed enough in the past

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: What techniques exist for creating a webpage feature which shows endless auto-scrolling of an embedded list of items?
I stuck to a singular topic all the way through in this post. After a few days of silence, someone felt it necessary to sweep it away with an excuse that it is not focused. I don't understand. It's literally about a singular topic. I detail where I need help in improving any number of shortcomings. Even just soliciting an answer that says "hey, let me show you this resource that teaches X which should help you with shortcoming 3" would be great.
What I want help with in the meta discussion here is what can be an acceptable question to the problem I have? I have a proof of concept, barely-functional code that if one line changes, it all shatters.
I even tried to post a "dumb" question (I want to create a price is right style wheel on a web page and I have no idea how) purposefully for the sake of showing that I need help and to not have them mistake my proof of concept as final good-to-go code.
Any guidance would be great. I hope that the week long saga on a singular topic from me shows I'm not some robot or troll trying to frustrate anyone. I sincerely want help. But if my topic is too high level for the community, I'd just like someone to say that and maybe congratulate me for asking about a topic beyond their scope of knowledge instead of closing threads under false and contradictory pretenses.

While I can see how this meta question is somewhat ranty it IS seeing input and I don't understand the closure votes here. Certainly it could use a substantial edit but the OP is clearly struggling to understand how SO works, and that's what Meta is for.

@Nickel I've done a very quick edit of your post to remove content that seemed at best tangential to what you want (getting feedback on your question) but is likely to goad people into negative reactions. If I've removed too much please feel free to put that back into your post.

It took me some time before I realised the OP was looking for an infinite/repeating vertical slider/carousel but perhaps did not know the keywords to search leading to some frustration in finding the right search results.

Step one would be to fix the formatting of that question. That is not how code formatting works...

Seems like a weirdly worded how to question to me “How do I create an infinitely scrolling div?” Given that, the question seems to include far more information than I’d expect necessary for that topic

@Cerbrus The formatting is how the editor wanted it from me. You can review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429764/bug-when-trying-to-post-a-question-with-code-in-it where I echo the sentiment. The webpage has a feature suggesting "use the ctrl+k to automatically format your code." or something like that. So I paste the code in, highlight the code, and press ctrl+k. But a warning remains of "unformatted code". The only way I could get it to go through was to put the ` around every line.

I fixed the formatting for you. I don't know how Ctrl+K got you an un-postable result...

@Paulie_D And very true, I lack the right jargon. The word "repeating" has many contexts, like in a simple repeating background-image. Slider gets me the scrollbars and stuff like that. Carousel is the closest I got, but I found a code example of someone doing 3D animations or what I would think of as a "slideshow". I can focus more on carousel in my next round of googling results to hopefully stumble upon some example that I can adapt.

Or create a  Stack Snippet using the <> icon for your code

I'm also not sure what your intention is with the nested quote formatting at the bottom of that question... You'll need to fix that, yourself.

I did try to make a stack snippet, but it didn't seem to work. But seeing the details on that webpage is helpful because I can see what is expected. I wonder if my NoScript extension prevented the Snippet editor from appearing to me. That's why I went with codepen.io links because at least that gave me the runnable code for people to use. But of course, "external code is unacceptable" because it could be changed, which is a fair critique, but that was my last recourse for showing the MRE when the Snippet editor didn't load for me.

Yeah, NoScript messes with a lot of functionality on a lot of sites... I wonder if that prevented you from formatting your code properly, as well.

Right now, my NoScript permits stackoverflow.com and ajax.googleapis.com. It blocks cookielaw.org and googletagmanager.com. Those are the only 4 domains on this very page as I make this comment. I will try to be mindful on the editor if other domains are requested and get blocked.

"Don't just close the question because you are humbled by the breadth of the problem.". You are a character, that's for sure :) Stack Overflow has a long list of rules, and even if you don't read that list of rules you can easily learn one thing from the existence of that list; not all questions are to be posted on Stack Overflow. If you seek guidance, there are so many websites available. I can see just some people on Reddit beckoning you. Please. Post it here. Post it here! We have so many opinions we want to share with you on this matter!

I wonder if 13 paragraphs were really necessary for that question. Questions typically have much less words than that.

As an aside: do not repost (10k link) what is nominally the same question in a radically different style - instead, actually fix your questions by editing them. Especially do not post them in a way that goes to an opposite extreme, and then run to Meta to complain that standards make it impossible to get the level of detail "just right" (everyone knows this is nonsense, because new questions are well received all the time). Especially do not also complain about the site in that question. Please show consideration for others.

If you are unwilling to whitelist stacksnippets.net in NoScript to make it work (entirely understandable - but note that it doesn't run anything until you hit the "Run code snippet" button, and this will generally also trigger an XSS warning), you can simply learn how the snippet Markdown works and insert it manually. It basically involves setting up a few "magic" HTML comments in the Markdown source.

First off: it helps a lot to avoid noise, redundancy and unclear formatting. When people look at the question and see just how far they have to scroll just to find the comment section and give feedback on the length (never mind actually reading through it all to understand the question, or reaching the answer field to offer the first answer). Curators who see a long question are predisposed to reach for the "Needs More Focus" close reason, because a properly focused question that really asks one thing with a suitable scope really shouldn't need that much text. Sure, some questions are necessarily longer than others - especially in the world of web dev, since even the simplest questions typically involve an interaction between HTML, CSS and JavaScript. However, it is definitely not necessary to go on for pages and pages.
Before I saw the question, someone else had already edited to fix some formatting - replacing (mostly broken) repeated use of inline code formatting, with more appropriate multi-line code block formatting. I further improved this by wrapping the HTML and associated CSS in a "snippet", allowing the demonstration to run locally and avoiding the need for CodePen. The snippet feature exists pretty much specifically to support web dev questions (it doesn't support any other programming languages).
Fixing these things - by reading the formatting help and checking the post preview before submitting - really helps with creating the impression that you care about making the post readable (and thus answerable) for others. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow questions are for everyone, not just you; a successful question will be read by many other people, and its answers will eventually help many other people.
I then edited the question - and title - to get to the point. Please carefully study the new version as an example. I'm not sure if regular users of the web dev tags will agree, but I think these changes expose a reasonably focused question. In the process of shortening the text, I incidentally avoided some other "needs more focus" red-flag phrases, like "I ask for an exhaustive list" and "Several problems exist with this approach" and "Please don't feel this question is too big for you".
For future reference, here is a list of things that IMO don't belong in questions:

Text that could be obviated by proper formatting (instead of starting paragraphs with "first", "second" etc., just use a bulleted list)

Anything to do with you (such as current mental state, plans for the future etc.) aside from the simple facts that you've written certain code or are trying to do some specific thing (and even then, only to the extent necessary to understand the question)

Any kind of "meta" commentary, such as the fact that you are trying to create a minimal reproducible example or that the community "covets" those. Instead, just show us the example. It took you 611 characters to tell us

The minimally reproducible example uses p elements for constructing the list, not a formal list, I am sorry to mislead anyone who thought I was using li elements, that was not my intention, but I thought the title more concise if I say "list of items" as opposed to "collective of p elements in an html document that are meant to represent concepts related to one another in excess of a quantity one". There are fewer letters to p than there are li and no need to wrap it in another element of ul or the sort, so that contributes to the minimually reproducible example so coveted in the community.

compared to the 60 that you saved on writing <p> and </p> instead of <ul> and </ul> (it should have been 30, even without the quibble that the list doesn't really need to be this long for a working demo), or the 60 that you saved by writing "list" instead of, say, "sequence" in various places in the question (again this should have been far less anyway). But even beyond space considerations, content like that goes on Meta, not in the main space.

Begging or pleading like "May such a person with knowledge be willing to share?", especially when it only requests help and does not ask a question directly.

Commentary on the perceived difficulty or complexity of the question

In particular, preemptive apologies or attempts to sympathize with the reader for the question length, fall into both the previous categories.

Redundant code - especially not a copy and paste of dozens of lines of joint CSS and HTML just to make a single-character change in the HTML. I was able to explain the point you were trying to make by highlighting one of the <p> elements with much less text while also not needing to refer to a modified example at all.

Complex metaphors for what you want - describe it directly instead.

Rephrasings of already stated ideas - put more effort into making it clear the first time.

Recaps or summaries - if you feel the need for them because the question is already long, this is only making matters worse.

Headings - for the same reason.

"Lead-ins" like "For those who don't want to see what the code does, that's great!". If you want to explain your approach to the code, then just do that - don't announce your intention to do so.

Flowery prose: for example, "how can I do X" is better than "what techniques exist for doing X"


Your attempt at the question had example of almost all of these. So it's hardly surprising that I was able to cut the code in half (and could, I suppose, have gone further) and the prose by over 70%. Seriously - I've basically written you a style manual here, repeating myself for emphasis etc. and it still comes in shorter than just the prose of your original question.

I appreciate it. This is a month after the fact, but as life gets busy, I haven't been able to tend to it. I am still struggling on the matter, so I'll review the post for the restructuring you gave in addition to this comment I am replying to. If I have not gotten adequate responses on answering the question at hand, what should I do? Abandon SO for this topic and seek other platforms, so I don't repost? Or do I edit the question again? Again, the time and effort you put into this comment to help me is apparent and appreciated.

"If I have not gotten adequate responses on answering the question at hand, what should I do?" - this, too, could be answered by looking through what is already written.

The "needs focus" close reason doesn't just mean "you're asking multiple questions"; it also means the question you have asked is too broad in scope. Any question asking to list all the possible ways to do something is too broad for Stack Overflow; we're not here to generate lists for programmers, we're here to answer specific, practical programming problems.
I have not fully read your question, but it may be salvageable if you edit it to ask "how do I do X" instead of asking "list all the ways I can do X".
Also, do avoid asking or even mentioning matters of opinion, such as your question's third concern,

Third, less serious, but a matter of elegance

As opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and mentioning this muddies the question and increases its likelihood of being closed, or at least of being poorly received.
Finally, definitely avoid self-aggrandizement:

I can't comprehend how this is not focused. It's laser focused. It's even sculpted, a true masterpiece the likes of da Vinci. [...]  Don't just close the question because you are humbled by the breadth of the problem.

We're not here to feed pet egos, either. Complimenting yourself on a question the community has closed rings pretty hollow, anyway.

I've voted to reopen your question.
Your question seems to be fine to me, at least in its current form (I didn't look at the edit history).
But, and I'm not going to mince any words here, your attitude comes off as being extremely arrogant for somebody asking for volunteer help from experts on the internet. The people here are people: they're human, not perfect. I guarantee some of the negative response to your question is due to your attitude about feedback rather than the actual question. Heck, I want to give you a negative response purely for your attitude, an impulse which I'm controlling at the moment with great difficulty.
You are not going to get very far by being condescending to people you are soliciting for hundreds of USD worth of free technical help.

I'd like to encourage you to have a look at that edit history. I put quite a bit of effort into reading the original version and distilling it into the current form. I do think it could be further reduced - for example, I'm not sure whether web devs would agree that the code example is necessary at all to explain the technique that OP hit upon.

@KarlKnechtel that's fair but if you managed to salvage it (and good on you for doing so) it should be re-opened. Even if the OP loses interest or rage quits it could be useful for posterity. I removed the bit about the feedback not being the greatest, it was (per your comment) probably appropriate at the time.

I mean, I cast the first reopen vote and you cast the second....
